# Remove underline from multiple radio button group within pageblocktable

Tags: visualforce

In my visual page am getting some list item from StandardController and assigning it to

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!objVar.variable}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Let me say the items will give the options like 'Yes','No' and 'May be'.Then am applying these values as an options for the radio group.
So all these values are coming properly as expected.
But the problem one underline is appearing at the bottom of the radio group.That is really annoying.
[image: issue]

I do not know how to remove.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Salesforce StackExchange. I edited your post to display the code. In the future, you can use http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code for help making it display properly. You will see a preview of your post directly below where you are editing it. Check it before you post.

Comment: Are you using any custom CSS? What element is your selectRadio inside of?

Comment: No am not using any custom CSS..And am using selectRadio inside of apex:pageblocktable

Comment: this is because of the pageBlockTable. I tried without the table and it does not show up the line beneath the radio buttons. I am looking to find a css solution to this.

Comment: Please share the solution if you able to solve this..

Comment: Solution:
I have just added the <script>....</script>code snippets suggessted by Simran (Which is accepted by me)
after my <apex:selectRadio>...</apex:selectRadio> code part
in the script i have just changed the id value based on my requirement.
That's it.It worked for me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines are the result of how SelectOption is rendered in a pageblock table. You have to use a small javascript code to get rid of those lines.

```
<apex:column> 
    <apex:selectRadio value="{!objVar.variable}" id="optionVal">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
    </apex:selectRadio>
    <script>
        var selectOptionTable = document.getElementById('{!$Component.optionVal}');
        var cells = selectOptionTable.getElementsByTagName('td');

        for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
            cells[i].style.border = 'none' ;
        }
    </script>
</apex:column>
```

Make sure the you use this script inside apex column or if you move it outside column tag, do make relevant changes in script code.

Comment: Yes the above code did the magic...
Thank you Simran..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding mode="edit" to the page block:

```
 <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a normal HTML table would eliminate the lines, since those are simply a feature of page blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As per Simran's idea I have added the script tag in between the `<apex:column>...</apex:column>` tags.
Only I had to add an Id for my `<apex:selectRadio..>` and replaced optionVal with my id.
That's it..

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply override style settings

```
<style>
body .pbBody table.list tr.dataRow th, body .pbBody table.list tr.dataRow td {
    border-bottom-width:0px;
}
</style>
```